# Tourist logic destination

Tags: logical-deduction

There is logic to the numbers of tourists who visited these places one day. How many tourists went to Denver that day and how are the numbers worked out?

```
Dallas-600
Chicago-201
Orlando-550
Denver-?
```

Comment: It's not at all unusual for some time to elapse between posting something and anyone trying to solve it, and I wouldn't suggest posting "will someone look at this?" comments -- if at all -- until, say, a day has passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number who went to Denver is

> 505

because

> the number associated with each city is the sum of the Roman numerals found in its name.